# How to add custom controls in WPF using MVVM and DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am basically using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11095460/1115382) code and I am successfully adding `CheckBox`es (instead of `ComboBox` that is in the example) to my `View`. The problem however is that I want to be able to customize (different `Content`, binding, etc) those `CheckBox`es. Right now when I add a `CheckBox` it adds the default one that is defined in my `DataTemplate`.

`DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CurrencyViewModel}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <CheckBox Content="Default"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

`CurrencyViewModel` - **the code here is NOT used by the program and I am not sure why, but I am pretty sure that this is the problem**

```
class CurrencyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CurrencyViewModel(ICurrency currency)
    {   
        CheckBox currencyCheckBox = new CheckBox()
        {
            Content = currency.Name,
        };
     OnPropertyChanged("CurrenciesList");
}
```

`MainViewModel`:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    foreach (ICurrency currencyin GetAllCurrencies())
    {
        CurrenciesList.Add(new CurrencyViewModel(currency));
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<CurrencyViewModel> _CurrenciesList = new ObservableCollection<CurrencyViewModel>();
public ObservableCollection<CurrencyViewModel> CurrenciesList
{
    get
    { return _CurrenciesList; }
    set
    {
        _CurrenciesList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrenciesList");
    }
}
```

Comment: Having a CheckBox in a ViewModel is ringing some alarm bells...

Comment: @goobering hard coding them is out of the question. Is there any better approach than this one?

Comment: For starters get rid of the CheckBox in your VM. You should only be storing the Name as a string in your CurrencyViewModel. Then set the Content property of the CheckBox in your DataTemplate to {Binding Name}.

Comment: @goobering I did what you told me and it seems that you are correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be putting `View` objects in your `ViewModel` - it breaks the pattern's intent (separation of business logic from presentation). `Checkbox`/`Combobox` choice should be made in the `View` based on the state, type or data contained by your `ViewModel` via `Binding`, `DataTemplates`, `Triggers`, etc.

I would re-evaluate your design as it's not compatible with MVVM as a pattern.

Comment: But I need to create controllers dynamically and then link in my first line says that the approach I have taken is the best one. Is it not correct? Should I be creating everything in code behind, because I need some business logic to get the information for each `CheckBox`?

Comment: The difference between your design and the linked solution is that the linked solution contains only properties to bind to, *not* interface elements.

Comment: Is the layout of every item the same? i.e. `Checkbox` with a currency name? If so, you just need to set the binding on the `Checkbox` in the `View` XAML and expose the currency name via a property in the `ViewModel` which you then bind to.