# adding new row dynamic to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am new with WPF and I am trying to add a new to the data grid I created.

The rows I am adding should be added dynamically however I can't see the values of the data in in the data grid.

Here is the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ProtocolAnalyzer.createByProtocol"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="createByProtocol" Height="506" Width="384">
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,4">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridTable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="452" Width="245">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Value"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ProtocolAnalyzer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for createByProtocol.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class createByProtocol : Window
    {
        private ProtocolData.ProtocolData.Protocols _runningProtocol;

        public class Data
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        public createByProtocol(ProtocolData.ProtocolData.Protocols protocol)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _runningProtocol = protocol;
            buildTable();
        }

        private void buildTable()
        {
            switch (_runningProtocol)
            {
                case  ProtocolData.ProtocolData.Protocols.ZBM:
                    dataGridTable.Items.Add("");
                    dataGridTable.Items[0] = "FFF";

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: some general information [for "dynamic controls" in wpf/mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095189/adding-controls-dynamically-in-wpf-mvvm/11095460#11095460)

if you go the MVVM style you do something like this.

viewmodel

```
//your data 
public ObservableCollection<Customer> MySource {get;set;}

//Command to add a new row
public ICommand AddNewCustomerCommand {get{return _lazyAddCommand.Value;}}

private readonly Lazy<DelegateCommand> _lazyAddCommand;

//ctor
public MyViewmodel()
{
   MySource = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
   _lazyAddCommand= new Lazy<DelegateCommand>(() => new DelegateCommand(AddNewCustomerCommandExecute, CanAddNewCustomerCommandExecute));
 }

 private bool CanAddNewCustomerCommandExecute()
 {
     return true;//your Conditions goes here
 }

 private void AddNewCustomerCommandExecute()
 {
     if (!CanAddNewCustomerCommandExecute())
            return;
      //Add new Customer
      MySource.Add(new Customer());
  }
```

view: use Binding to set the ItemsSource for your Datagrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Value"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

thats all. the new row will display as far as your command is invoked through a button or something else

Answer (score 1):

if you have data in "DataTable" that you are trying to assign to datagrid then you can use datagrid.Datasource porperty

If you have a list or an array..
then just use foreach loop and under that loop add you rows.

Comment: can you please give a code example of how to add the rows in a loop?

Comment: For example i have a an array of string that has my items..
string[] MyItems=new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };

foreach(string item in MyItems)
{
dataGridTable.Items.Add(item);

}