# WPF MVVM - ViewModel First add controls to the same groupbox

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I created my MVVM Pattern according to this SO [Adding controls dynamically in wpf mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095189/adding-controls-dynamically-in-wpf-mvvm)

My datatemplate looks like this:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Product_Configurator:ModelParametersViewModel}">
        <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="groupBox" Header="Standard"  >
            <Grid x:Name="grpStandard" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding AttributeName}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource Configurator_Value_Box}" Text="{Binding EvalValue}"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

## This is how my view looks like:

[image: MyView]
but actually I want all the labels and textboxes in the same groupbox. How do I achieve this?

Comment: simply remove the GroupBox from your DataTemplate and put the ItemsControl with the Collection of Product_Configurator:ModelParametersViewModels in a GroupBox?

Comment: awesome, somehow it was too obvious for me too see it, thanks. Post it as answer so I can mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the GroupBox from your DataTemplate and put the ItemsControl with the Collection of Product_Configurator:ModelParametersViewModels in a GroupBox