# ObservableCollection of controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I am working on program that use wpf with design of mvvm.
I have a collection of Control, each item can be Button\RadioButton\TextBox ...

```
ObservableCollection<Control> controls_lst = new ...
```

I want to iterate over this list by the xaml code of the view, and create and display each control.
but the problem is that i need to check the type before i write

there is a way to iterate over this list and create and display the control by checking the type from the **xaml** ? i

Comment: ObservableCollection<Control> is not mvvm ;). check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095189/adding-controls-dynamically-in-wpf-mvvm answer here to get an understanding.

Comment: You would usually have an ObservableCollection with different types of data items. Then declare a DataTemplate for each type of data item, and bind the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl to the ObservableCollection. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Why do you need to check the type?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should never define collections of controls or any other UI element. If this collection is defined in a view model, this would also violate the *MVVM* pattern. A collection of controls eliminates all the flexibility to create controls dynamically.

   The recommended way is to define item models and let them dynamically render with the help of a corresponding `DataTemplpate` and an `ItemsControl`:

   **Data model definitions**

   ```
   // Common base type
   interface ISelectorItem
   {
     public string Text { get; set; }
   }

   // Model to represent a ToggleButton
   class BooleanItem : ISelectorItem
   {
   }
   ```

   **ViewModel.cs**

   ```
   class ViewModel
   {
     public ObservableCollection<ISelectorItem> DataModels { get; set; }

     public ViewModel()
     {
       this.DataModels = new ObservableCollection<ISelectorItem>() { new BooleanItem() { Text = "Click Me"}};
     }
   }
   ```

   **MainWindow.xaml**

   ```
   <Window>
     <Window.DataContext>
       <ViewModel />
     </Window.DataContext>

     <Window.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type BooleanItem}">
         <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Text}" />
       </DataTemplate>
     </Window.Resources>

     <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataModels}" />
   </Window>
   ```

---

2. You can use a `DataTrigger` in conjunction with a custom type converter (also works with solution 1):

   **Implementation of `TypeConverter` (`IValueConverter`)**

   ```
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
     => value.GetType();
   ```

   **View implementation**

   ```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionWithControls}">
     <ListView.Resources>
       <TypeConverter x:Key="TypeConverter" />
     </ListView.Resources>
     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResources TypeConverter}} 
                        Value="{x:Type RadioButton}">
             <Setter ... />
           </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ListView>
   ```

---

3. Use `DataTemplate`:

   ```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionWithControls}">
     <ListView.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type RadioButton}">

         <!-- Type specific layout -->
         ...
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.Resources>
   </ListView>
   ```